# tex4ht: wrapping title with a custom tag

Tags: titles, tex4ht, html

The `\maketitle` command in my LaTeX source is rendered in HTML by `tex4ht` as

```
<div class="maketitle">
<h2 class="titleHead">My Title</h2>
<div class="author" >My Author</div><br />
<div class="date" >2016</div>
</div>
```

which is almost fine (apart from a lot of useless spaces and newlines I polished it from), I only would like to see it wrapped in tag (additional or replacing the external `div` tag) like

```
<section class="titlepage">
...
</section>
```

How can I obtain that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\Configure{maketitle}`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\Configure{maketitle}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<section class="titlepage">}\NoFonts}%
{\EndNoFonts\HCode{</section>}}%
{\HCode{<h2 class="titleHead">}}{\HCode{</h2>}}
\EndPreamble
```

see also some [documentation details](http://michal-h21.github.io/src4ht/tex4ht-infose5.html#x10-70002.5) on `\maketitle` configuration. What is interesting is use of `\NoFonts` ... `\EndNoFonts`, which suppress insertion of `<span>` elements with font information. Resulting elements:

```xml
 <section class="titlepage">


<h2 class="titleHead">My title</h2>
<div class="author" >My Author</div><br />
<div class="date" >2016</div>

   </section>
```

Comment: I assume your code should be used as a custom configuration file specified at compilation time, isn't it? I inserted the `\Configure` instruction after `\begin{document}` in my custom configuration file and it works.

Comment: @mmj sure, I always post custom configuration files, I didn't mention it this time :)